# Jira: Best way to setup issue for having info about responsible users (analyst, developer, qa)

Tags: jira

I'm looking for best way to have possibility to find out from jira issue -who was responsible for certain stages of its lifecycle.

Our work process on issue starts from analysis then going development and quality assurance.

One way to find out such information is Transitions tab of issue, but if issue was hardly reopened or returned from qa to development understand responsible user from "Transitions" seems a little bit confusing.

So, I wonder if there are another ways (may be some plugin) to store information about users which have been involved in work on issue.

If there is a way to store them (involved users) by their roles in project (analyst, developer, qa) it would be perfect!

Comment: Participants field of the [Jira Toolkit Plugin (free)](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.toolkit/cloud/overview) may help. IIRC that will give you everybody who has ever been involved with an issue (was its assignee and/or commented on it)

Comment: Is it something really useful? In this way really too many people might be involved.
If I think about my tickets, I can have PO commenting, QA commenting, SM updating something in the ticket (Epic, Component, Label..), DEVS interacting on them.
Result: I see a scenario where basically all tickets have almost everybody involved. Personally I don't see where this could be useful, not much more than mere statistics.

Comment: May I ask that you expand the question to include your use case? As a (what), you want to do this so that you can (what)?

Comment: Jira tickets have Activity feed that track all the activity on a ticket.

Comment: Create custom fields in Jira and track there the info that you want to track.

Answer (score 1):

So your question is how to setup JIRA in order to facilitate this process?

In my team we **simply used sub-tasks**. Each issue / story is split into sub-tasks some that can run in parallel (coding, design, documentation, ) or in sequence. 
This way each sub-task is assigned to a team member responsible to carry out that activity and on stand-up meetings they can 'move' their task to in-progress once preceding tasks are moved to 'Done'

Having to find out who worked on story is easy as finding all sub-tasks of a task..

Answer (score 0):

If people leave comments when changing the status, then you can setup an issue which is simply a link to the comments feed of a JQL query for a set of issues. For example:

[image: ASF JIRA Comments Feed for Cordova Issues]

**References**

- [ASF JIRA Apache Cordova Comments Feed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-comments-rss/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=project+%3D+"Apache+Cordova"+and+status+was+in+%28"In+Implementation"%2C+"In+Progress"%29+after+startOfYear%28%29++and+assignee+was+not+EMPTY&tempMax=1000)
- [Apache CouchDB Comments Feed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-comments-rss/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=project+%3D+"CouchDB"+and+status+was+in+%28"In+Implementation"%2C+"In+Progress"%29+before+startOfYear%28%29++and+assignee+was+not+EMPTY&tempMax=1000)
- [Receiving Search Results as an RSS Feed - Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira062/receiving-search-results-as-an-rss-feed-588581779.html)